# Как отделить роль крестика от роли кнопки во всплывающем окне?

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton, pyqt6, qmessagebox

У меня есть всплывающее окно:

```
...

popup = QMessageBox(self)
popup.setWindowTitle("Заголовок")
popup.move(400, 300)
popup.setText("Текст")

agreeButton = popup.addButton("Agree", QMessageBox.ButtonRole.YesRole)

popup.setDefaultButton(agreeButton)
popup.exec()
if popup.clickedButton() == agreeButton:
    print("Кнопка 'Agree' нажата")
...
```

По идее, только после нажатия на кнопку **`Agree`** 
оно должно выводить **`Кнопка 'Agree' нажата`**, но почему-то оно также выводит это сообщение если нажать на крестик закрытия окна.

Возможно как-то совпадают роли, но я пробовал поставить для кнопки роли `YesRole`, `NoRole` и `ApplyRole`, но во всех случаях нажатие на крестик тоже провоцировало вывод текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что закрытие всплывающего окна (**QMessageBox**) при нажатии на крестик или клавишу Esc по умолчанию интерпретируется как нажатие кнопки "Отмена" (Cancel). В вашем коде проверка `popup.clickedButton() == agreeButton` будет истинной и при закрытии окна.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно изменить стандартное поведение кнопки "Отмена" для всплывающего окна. Можно сделать это, установив флаг `QMessageBox.RejectRole` для кнопки "Отмена".

Вот исправленный код:

```
popup = QMessageBox(self)
popup.setWindowTitle("Заголовок")
popup.move(400, 300)
popup.setText("Текст")
agreeButton = popup.addButton("Agree", QMessageBox.ButtonRole.YesRole)
cancelButton = popup.addButton("Cancel", QMessageBox.ButtonRole.RejectRole)
popup.setDefaultButton(agreeButton)
popup.exec()

clickedButton = popup.clickedButton()
if clickedButton == agreeButton:
    print("Кнопка 'Agree' нажата")
elif clickedButton == cancelButton:
    print("Кнопка 'Cancel' нажата")
```

Теперь проверка `clickedButton == agreeButton` будет истинной только при нажатии кнопки "Agree", а не при закрытии окна.

Comment: Спасибо! У кнопки `Cancel` роль `RejectRole` стоит по умолчанию, так что ее можно даже не присваивать.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
#PyQt6 from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centerWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self._popup)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centerWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)        
        
        self.popup = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
        self.popup.setWindowTitle("Заголовок")
        self.popup.move(400, 300)
        self.popup.setText("Текст")
#PyQt6  agreeButton = popup.addButton("Agree", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.ButtonRole.YesRole)
        agreeButton = self.popup.addButton("Agree", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.YesRole)
        agreeButton.setCheckable(True)
        agreeButton.setAutoDefault(False)
        agreeButton.setDefault(False)
        self.popup.setFocus()
        self.popup.installEventFilter(self)
        
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.popup.hide()
            return True
        return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, widget, event)
        
    def _popup(self):
        self.popup.exec()
        if self.popup.clickedButton() and self.popup.clickedButton().isChecked():
            print("Кнопка 'Agree' нажата")
            self.popup.clickedButton().click()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]